# Why won't my digitalocean droplet return anything from my API request

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I'm trying to host my nodejs app on a digital ocean droplet, the nodejs app runs a function every 2 minutes that makes a request to this API and then saves the returned data in a mongodb database.

Here is my code...

```
const headers = {
        "accept-charset" : "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        "accept-language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2",
        "accept-encoding" : "gzip,deflate",
    };

    const options = {
        url: `https://api.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml.gz?affiliate_key=${API_KEY}&event_type=football-single_event`,
        headers: headers
    };

    const requestWithEncoding = (options, callback) => {
        const req = request.get(options)

        req.on('response', res => {

            var chunks = []
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                chunks.push(chunk)
            })

            res.on('end', () => {

                const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
                const encoding = res.headers['content-type']

                if(encoding.includes('gzip')){

                    zlib.gunzip(buffer, (err, decoded) => {
                        callback(err, decoded && decoded.toString())
                    })

                } else {
                    
                    callback('Data error', buffer.toString())

                }
            })
        })

        req.on('error', err => {
            callback(err)
        })
    }

    requestWithEncoding(options, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('F error 1: ', err)
        } else {
            // this changes XML format to JSON format
            parseString(data, (err, result) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log('F error 2: ', err)
                } else {

                    console.log(result)
                }
            })

        }
    })
```

The server keeps returning "F error 1: Data error", however this doesn't on the same ubuntu 20.04 server when hosted on aws and it never happens when I run the same code on my computer locally. Does anyone know why this is? Am I setting my droplet up wrong?

Comment: then what is the error ?

Comment: Oh sorry, the err is "Data error", so I guessing the returned data isn't in gzip format

Comment: I've looked into it and the return is in text/html format. Why is that happening?

Comment: If you're wondering why it's sending you HTML, then perhaps it's because of this header: `"accept" : "text/html"`.

Comment: Ah ok, do you know what the header should be? the data is usually returned in gzip format